# SMD Diode Component Identification

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I am very new on this site and new to electronics. I need to ask for your help in identifying an SMD component. This is what it says on it. 0C ш
Please help if you can.
It's 0C and what looks like a capital E lying flat on its back.
It is in a back light for my car. A Mercedes Benz ML550
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question: (1) Fix the title to reflect the contents of your question. The existing title is useless. (2) Add a photo. There's an image button on the toolbar. How did you miss it? (3) Give context. What does the circuit it is in do.

Comment: The photo is a big help but I don't recognise it. Someone will.

Comment: mostly likely a diode with the sloped end marking the cathode

Comment: Could you add a rough measurement of the device (size of the black bit) so the package can be narrowed down.

Comment: Also, it is more likely a 0 (zero) not a O

Comment: If you have a multimeter then check it both ways on resistance and diode test. Add the results to your original post.

Comment: I thought it was a digit and not a letter. Thanks for the observation. I will try to take the measurement and update it.

Comment: I did test it and my meter says it's a Zener diode with a reverse voltage of 5.534V and a forward voltage of 0.777V That's the good one. There are 3 of them in the circuit. One is good and 2 are out.

Comment: http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm Look under O

Comment: TC you are an angel, I mean that. Thank you so much i will try to see who's got it. I probably wouldn't have known this without your help. I really do appreciate it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @TeachMe Assuming you have determined that the component is faulty, have you tried to find out what made it fail? Otherwise, the replacement is likely to fail because of the same problem.

Comment: I am not too sure yet so i'm going to order 10 times more than what i need just in case.

Answer (score 4):

It is the MM3Z5V6T1G - a 5.6V Zener diode from OnSemi in SOD-323 package.

From the [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MM3Z2V4T1-D.PDF) we can see the following marking scheme:

[image: Diode Marking]

Note the date code location - placed at 90 degrees as you see in yours.

Also note that yours does have the Pb-free microdot in the bottom location (both are possible).

We can also decode the exact part number from the table in the datasheet:

[image: Part Number]

The 0C indicates it is the 5.6V version.

The package also matches the lead style in your photograph.

Comment: TC you are an angel, I mean that. Thank you so much i will try to see who's got it. OMG!